# Multi - User Multi Environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm looking to create an app, where each user can create their own... "Universe" in a way, with the amount of items and names that makes sense to them, etc.

I've never done this before, so far I've had the typical cases where you have users and admins, but they're both looking essentially at the same thing. Here each user will have a separate environment.

Obviously a user should not be able to see someone else's environment.

Can someone please point me to the right direction on this subject? Maybe some useful gems or resources I could use to get started?

Any advice is welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd start with using a plugin for authentication, e.g. [AuthLogic](https://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic) or [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) are two popular examples.

Both of these let you define a `User` class.

Then, when you are showing the user their stuff in their environment, you can make sure you only show them their own stuff by using `has_many`, and `has_one`, and `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationships in rails.

e.g. if it was facebook, you might have something like this

```
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :news_items
  has_many :friends
  has_many :messages
end
```

In your code you could then refer to

```
@user.news_items
@user.friends
@user.messages
```

And the relationships would ensure you were only showing information belonging to that user.

(Caveat: in reality the relationships will be more complicated, and you will probably need more complicated logic, but this should get you started)

Comment: Thanks a lot! It makes sense, however, doesn't it become a bit code consumptive? I mean, if assuming I have one user, I would work with model Message. @messages = Message.find(:all) now, in every bit I would need to go @messages = Message.where(:user=>session[user_id])...? Or something like this?

Comment: No, if you have a has_many relationship from User to messages, you can do @user.messages directly - no need to do a find on the message class.